# Generate the MouseClick in MonkeyRunner

Tags: android, testing, jython, monkeyrunner

I am new in android, Please tell me how we can generate the mouseclick event on the any application using monkeyrunner Jython script. Please give me some hint, how to write the code of mouseclick event.

Thanks in advance...!!!

Comment: There is no such thing as a mouseclick event in Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no any such way to Generate the MouseClick in MonkeyRunner using the Jython Script. Because using this script we can generate only touch event and key press event. So try to generate mouseclick event is the waisting your time...!!!

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/MonkeyDevice.html#touch has information about the touch method of MonkeyRunner.MonkeyDevice. You will probably also want to read more of that guide to get a feel of how monkeyrunner works.